# Use Google Sheets to encode HTML into HTML Special Characters

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-sheets

I am trying to encode a block of HTML in a cell so that HTML can be displayed on a webpage wrapped in `<pre>` tags.

So

```
<div class="html"> 
    <html> 
    <head>
<title>Title</title>
</head> 
    <body>
    <p>Unrendred html</p>     </body> 
    </html> 
</div>
```

becomes

```
<pre>
&lt;div class="html"&gt;
    &lt;html&gt;
    &lt;head&gt;&lt;title&gt;Title&lt;/title&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
    &lt;body&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Unrendred html&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/body&gt;
    &lt;/html&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
</pre>
```

Now I thought I had cracked by finding the `=ENCODEURL` formula, but that outputs a slightly different output.

```
%26lt%3Bdiv%20class%3D%26quot%3Bhtml%26quot%3B%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3Bhtml%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3Bhead%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3Btitle%26gt%3BTitle%26lt%3B%2Ftitle%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3B%2Fhead%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3Bbody%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3Bp%26gt%3BUnrendred%20html%26lt%3B%2Fp%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3B%2Fbody%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3B%2Fhtml%26gt%3B%20%26lt%3B%2Fdiv%26gt%3B
```

This [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ormYNV) shows the ideal output and how I can successfully display HTML code within HTML.

I think the "encoding" option is called HTML Special Characters. How can I get this in Google Sheets? Perhaps via a formula or regex

Answer (score 1):

I'm accessing my Google Spread sheet cell via JSON and I've added the HTML there.

Google Spread Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17zfaoB56EfdSc9IzkJitSRi5wLGv-GJQwZaOPj5cZM0/edit#gid=0

Google Spread Sheet JSON: 
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/17zfaoB56EfdSc9IzkJitSRi5wLGv-GJQwZaOPj5cZM0/1/public/full?alt=json

Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/aystarz52/pen/ormamN?editors=1011

```js
$(function(){
  var sheetUrl = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/cells/17zfaoB56EfdSc9IzkJitSRi5wLGv-GJQwZaOPj5cZM0/1/public/full?alt=json';
  $.getJSON(sheetUrl, function(data){
    var entry = data.feed.entry;
    var htmlCode = []; // the leftmost column of the Google Sheets
  for (var i = 0; i < entry.length; i += 1){
      // entry[i].content.$t retrieves the content of each cell
      htmlCode.push(entry[i].content.$t);
    }
    var uri= escape_html(htmlCode);
    var res = escape(uri);
    var appendContents = document.getElementById("demo").textContent = uri; 
  })
});

function escape_html(str) {

 if ((str===null) || (str===''))
       return false;
 else
   str = str.toString();

  var map = {
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&#x00022;',
    "'": '&#039;',
  ";": '&#x0003B;'
  };

  return str.replace(/[<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
```

Here are the encoding characters: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref